Let $H$ and $K$ be normal subgroups of $G$. What is meant by "$G = H \times K$"?
I am looking at the following problem from Chapter 1 Section 8 of Hungerford:


Let $H, K, N$ be nontrivial normal subgroups of a group $G$ and suppose $G=H \times K$. Prove that $N$ is in the center of $G$ or $N$ intersects one of $H, K$ nontrivially. Give examples to show that both possibilities can actually occur when $G$ is nonabelian.


I am confused by what is meant by $G = H \times K$. I know it probably means $G \cong H \times K$, so there is an isomorphism $\varphi: H \times K \to G$ between them, but can I assume the isomorphism works well with the inclusion maps? Like can I assume the isomorphism is $\varphi(h,k) = hk$ so that $\varphi(h,e) = h$ and similarly $\varphi(e,k) = k$? I'm guessing Hungerford didn't use $\cong$ precisely because he's saying that $\varphi$ specifically is an isomorphism, but I'm just not sure. I have a proof of the statement, but it relies somewhat on whatever isomorphism existing between $G$ and $H \times K$ respecting the inclusion maps. Especially because if $\varphi$ is the isomorphism, I can immediately conclude $H \cap K = \{ e\}$ and elements of $H$ and $K$ commute with each other.

See what https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups#Algebraic_structure has to say about the internal direct product.

Ok, that solves my problem. I missed a remark on notation on page 62 that "We write $G = \prod_{i=1}^w N_i$ to indicate that the group $G$ is the internal weak direct product of the family of its subgroups ${ N_i | i \in I}$."
